# Unable to bind directive

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I want to create a directive so that the user can specify the text-transformation of an input by setting a property on the element as opposed to manually specifying the class or by manually specifying the styling.

What I did was add the following to my app.component.css:

```
.capitalize-input {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.lowercase-input {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.uppercase-input {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.capitalize-input:placeholder-shown
.lowercase-input:placeholder-shown,
.uppercase-input:placeholder-shown {
    text-transform: none;
}
```

I then setup the following directive in a file named text-transform.directive.ts

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Renderer2, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: `input[transform], input[mat-input][transform]`
})
export class TextTransformDirective implements OnChanges, OnInit {

    @Input() transform: 'capitalize' | 'lowercase' | 'uppercase';

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,
                private el: ElementRef) {}

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        if (!changes.transform) {
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, '.capitalize-input');
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, '.lowercase-input');
            this.renderer.removeClass(this.el.nativeElement, '.uppercase-input');
            return;
        }

        this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, `${changes.transform.currentValue}-input`);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        if (!!this.transform) {
            this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, `${this.transform}-input`);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I added the newly created directive to app.module.ts' declarations:

```
import { TextTransformDirective } from './library/text-transform/text-transform.directive';
//...
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TextTransformDirective
]
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Can't bind to 'transform' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.

I've read up on this error on various other StackOverflow articles and I thought that I did everything correctly. What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: You should add that directive to declarations array of NgModule where you use this directive. Or add it to SharedModule and import that module to NgModule

Comment: @yurzui - I figured out the issue shortly after. I had to export the directive in my library's module.

Comment: Great! I'm glad to hear you sorted it out.